# Como somar elementos (inteiros) de uma lista com inteiros de uma variavel?

Tags: python

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, em relação ao código abaixo.

```
x = 1, 1  # direita cima
menos_x = -1, 1  # esquerda cima
y = 1, -1  # direita baixo
menos_y = -1, -1   # esquerda baixo

lista = [x, menos_x, y, menos_y]

def walk():
    pos_inicial = 0, 0
    random_walk = random.choice(lista)
    pfinal = pos_inicial + random_walk
    print(pfinal)


print(lista) #Apenas para mostrar a lista
walk()
```

O resultado:

```
[(1, 1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1)]
(0, 0, 1, -1)
```

Mas o que eu preciso é, pegar um elemento aleatório da lista[] e somar com a variável pos_inicial, o que no exemplo acima, deveria sair:

```
(1, -1)
```

Consegui explicar direito minha dúvida?

EDIT: Basicamente, quero somar elementos de duas listas.

Exemplo:

```
lista1 = [1, 1]
lista2 = [2, 2]
soma = lista1 + lista2
```

resultado

```
(1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Mas eu gostaria que os valores fossem somados dessa forma:

```
(3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

O operador + em tuplas é equivalente à concatenação.
Você tem que somar cada elemento individualmente, no caso de seu código:

```
pfinal = pos_inicial[0] + random_walk[0],pos_inicial[1] + random_walk[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente sua dúvida, você precisa somar os dois itens das tuplas, resultando em uma nova tupla.

Você pode fazer o seguinte, na linha em que cria a variável `pfinal`:

```
pfinal = pos_inicial[0] + random_walk[0], pos_inicial[1] + random_walk[1]
```

Isso te retorna uma nova tupla com o resultado da soma das outras duas tuplas, acessando cada item que precisa ser somado pelo seu índice. Da forma que está fazendo atualmente, resulta em uma nova tupla com os itens das tuplas incluídas.

Isso acontece porque a ação de usar o operador `+` nas tuplas resulta em uma concatenação e não na soma dos itens, dado que o interpretador não saberia quais são os tipos dos itens a somar e se a operação de soma para cada item seria válida, nem a garantia de que ambas as tuplas teriam o mesmo tamanho, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você define que "x = 1,1" você não está criando uma lista e sim uma tupla.
Sua variável de nome "lista", é um objeto do tipo lista com 4 elementos do tipo tupla.
As implementações respondidas acima resolvem o seu problema.
No entanto, para que você consiga o resultado que você quer, da forma que você quer, somar duas listas, por exemplo:

```
print(x+y) 
>>>[3,3]
```

É possível utilizando a biblioteca numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,1])
y = np.array([2,2])
print(x+y)
>>>[3,3]
```